# Passing an Object between Table View Controller and it's Detail View Controller, getting NSInvalidArgumentException error

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I have been trying to solve this problem for quite some time now. I am having some difficulty passing a "Container" Object from a Table View Controller called ListTableViewController to its Detail View called "ListViewController" (I know I should probably change its name). Everytime I try to access the Container.name attribute of the Container object I get a NSInvalidArgument Errors and I don't know why, I am not even sure if the object is being passed properly although it seems like it should. Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

**I am trying to access currentContainer in ListViewController**

This is the code for my segue in ListTableViewController.m, which seems to work well:
The NSLog in this block gives me the expected Container name which is "salad".

```
#import "ListTableViewController.h"
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
#import "Container.h"

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
  {
    ListViewController *pvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    //What is the selected Cell?
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    Container *c = _containers[path.row];
    pvc.currentContainer = c;
    NSLog(@"%@",c.name);
}
```

My ListViewController.h has

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Container.h"
#import "ListTableViewController.h"

@interface ListViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) Container *currentContainer;

@end
```

And my ListViewConroller.m has

```
#import "Container.h"
#import "ListViewController.h"
#import "ListTableViewController.h"


@interface ListViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *containerName;

@end


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    //UILabel *container = [UILabel currentContainer name];
    NSLog(@"%@",_currentContainer);
    NSLog(@"%@",_containerName);
    //self.containerName.text = @"test";
    //self.title = _currentContainer.name;
    self.containerName.text = [self.currentContainer name];
}
```

This is the NSLOG values I have and stack trace:

```
2014-04-26 22:48:26.452 freshlids[58546:60b] Salad
2014-04-26 22:48:26.455 freshlids[58546:60b] <UILabel: 0x986a640; frame = (20 143; 280 30); text = 'Label'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM;     userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9869c20>>
2014-04-26 22:48:26.455 freshlids[58546:60b] <UILabel: 0x986a640; frame = (20 143; 280 30); text = 'Label'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM;     userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9869c20>>
2014-04-26 22:48:26.456 freshlids[58546:60b] -[UILabel name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x986a640
2014-04-26 22:48:26.459 freshlids[58546:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel name]: unrecognized selector sent to     instance 0x986a640'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: For some reason, the run time environment thinks "`[self.currentContainer name]`" is a UILabel?  are you sure you know what you're setting when you do "`pvc.currentContainer =`"?  What happens when you do a "`NSLog(@"%@",pvc.currentContainer)`" immediately after setting it?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Actually, `self.currentContainer` is a `UILabel`.

Comment: Aren't you just trying to access the text of an existing `UILabel`? If so you can do something like this `[self.currentContainer text]`. To be honest, I dont think you should be passing viewControllers around like that to child view controllers, instead, wouldn't it be better to pass data models down instead? But thats a different topic as a whole, more code refactoring. For now though, try what I mentioned at the beginning.

Comment: redoing comment as this thing won't let me edit the comment: This is what 2014-04-26 23:58:08.696 freshlids[58977:60b] <Container: 0x998f920> when I do NSLog(@"%@",pvc.currentContainer)

Comment: @Pavan no, I am trying to access the name property of a Container object. However if it would just be easier to pass the name tet from one view to another and not the object itself that would do for now, but what I am really trying to pass is the whole object so I can access all its attributes from the ListViewConroller view.

Comment: This seems like a bizarre problem -- there's nothing in the code you posted that should lead the compiler to think that currentContainer is a UILabel. Have you tried the usual things, like doing a Clean, shutting down Xcode, restarting, etc.?

Comment: @rdelmar I know I am really stumped with this one and I am a bit of an xcode ios noob so it makes it all the more difficult to debug. I don't know what a clean is and I have not restarted xcode, I will try restarting my computer etc. I must also say that I am using Restkit and Cocoapods... Restkit is being used to get a json object from a Rails API that I then map to a container....

Comment: Can you upload the project somewhere that we could test it ourselves?

Comment: I could sure, let me do that.

Comment: @rdelmarhere is the project: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byn9RQU6GAnicjBJU2pZMkJpcFU/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you must have set up currentContainer as a IBOutlet at some point (but you're not doing that now), because in the storyboard, I see currentContainer connected as an outlet to the same label that containerName is hooked up to. Delete that connection, and I think it should work correctly.

Comment: You are a life saver, that was exactly it, I am not sure how that happened but that was exactly the problem. I edited the storyboard in Source Code Mode found the outlet and manually deleted it and it worked. If I could buy you a six pack right now I would. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

Unless you have implemented a category or informal protocol that extends `UILabel`, `UIView`, `UIResponder`, or `NSObject`, `UILabel` does not respond to the selector `name`.

`self.currentContainer` is returning a `UILabel`, not an instance of your `Container` class (which would, I assume, respond to `name`.

Comment: This really isn't an answer. All it does is summarize the known issues. It would be better to post an answer that actually solves the issue.

Comment: Your question seems to be about the exception you are getting. My answer focused on that. You are calling ``name`` on a UILabel. Your question does not have information that would help troubleshoot why this is happening, and your comments seem to indicate this is something you expect. If you are looking to get something else out of your question I suggest you rethink and revise it. Are you looking to find out *why* currentContainer is a UILabel (you would need to show how _containers is populated)? What is the outcome you are seeking?